# Are all the R-R-bimodules completely reducible?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $R$ be the hyperfinite $II_1$ factor and let $X$ be any $R$-$R$-bimodule.

> **Question**: Is $X$ completely reducible (i.e. a direct integral of irreducible $R$-$R$-bimodules)?

**Example**: If $(N \subset M)$ is an irreducible, finite depth and finite index (hyperfinite $II_1$) subfactor, then $_NL^{2}(M)_N$ is completely reducible.

Comment: Are there some other properties of the bimodules you're considering that you forgot to mention? Otherwise, there are plenty of irreducible bimodules, like the irreducible bimodules corresponding to the vertices of the principal graph of your favorite finite index hyperfinite subfactor...

Comment: You will need direct intgerals.

Comment: @DavePenneys: I'm sorry, the word *reducible* was not appropriate, I've replaced it by *completely reducible*. I ask the question in general, but I'm particularly interested in the generic example I wrote.

Comment: Your example $_NL^2M_N$ has finite statistical dimension and is therefore completely reducible.

Comment: @AndréHenriques : thank you! So you say that a $R-R$ bimodule with finite statistical dimension is always completely reducible, why ? reference? What's this dimension for this example ?

Comment: ([Correspondence](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/popa-correspondences.pdf), Popa, p 24) The index of a $N-M$ bimodule $H$ (correspondence) is $dim_N(H).dim_M(H)$. So in my example, this index is $[M:N]^2$.

Comment: @AndréHenriques I didn't find (in Popa's note above) a theorem about the complete reducibility of finite index bimodules. There's just a half page on the type of a correspondence (p27) : << As we have seen, a correspondence $H$ between $N$ and $M$ is in fact a unital *-representation $\pi$ of $N \otimes M°$ on $H$. So we may speak about the type of the correspondence as being the type of $\pi$. Thus $H$ can be irreducible, factorial, of type $I$, $II$, $III$, etc. >>

Comment: It's certainly well known. I don't know the original reference, but it appears as Lemma 4.10 of my paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5671v1.pdf

Comment: @AndréHenriques : thank you very much! Just a detail : why $_NL^{2}(M)_N$ is dualizable? I've found in your paper that the dualizable bimodules are completely reducible and have finite statistical dimension, and so finite index, but I've no found a prove that finite index bimodules are dualizable, is it also proved ?

Comment: Yes, this is proven in my paper. The relevant definitions and propositions are: Definition 5.1, Definition 5.10, Warning 5.11, Lemma 5.16, Proposition 7.5, and Corollary 7.14.

Comment: @AndréHenriques : Thanks, very useful paper ! All these prove that $_NL^{2}(M)_M$ is dualizable. What for $_NL^{2}(M)_N$ ? Perhaps by taking $\pi_r(N)$ and $\pi_l(N)$ in $B(L^{2}(M))$ and the subfactor  $A=\pi_r(N) \subset \pi_l(N)'=B$ because then $_NL^{2}(M)_N \simeq _AL^{2}(B)_B$, right ?

Comment: $_NL^2M_N = _NL^2M\boxtimes_M L^2M_N$.

Comment: For the example this is well known, as André pointed out. This bimodule corresponds to the dual canonical endomorphism. In particular this bimodule has the structure of a special symmetric *-Frobenius algebra in the category of bimodules.

Comment: @Sébastian: Actually from Andrés last post follows that ${}_NL^2M_N$ is self-dual, this statement gets trvivial using the graphical calculus. It also follows from the fact that that it has the structure of a Frobenius algebra object.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: Thank you for your comment. I would like to better understand this bimodule. I know that $_NL^{2}(M) \boxtimes_M L^{2}(M^{op})_N$ is the direct sum of the irreducible bimodules at depth 0 and 2 (with multiplicities) in the principal graph of $N \subset M$, but $_NL^{2}(M)_N = _NL^{2}(M)  \boxtimes_M L^{2}(M)_N \neq  _NL^{2}(M) \boxtimes_M L^{2}(M^{op})_N$ in general, right? So what is the decomposition into irreducible for $_NL^{2}(M)_N$ ? For example, for $N=R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R=M$ with $\mathbb{A}$ a Kac algebra ?

Comment: @Sébastian: I don't see why you want the "op". I never saw any article using the "op", where do you got this from. I usually think in terms of endomorphisms/sectors not in terms of bimodules. Then it is an old result by Longo that finite index, depth two subfactors are in correspondence with Kac algebras. In general, every depth 2 inclusion is a fixed point of a locally compact quantum group in the sense of Woronowizc.

Comment: In this case ${}_NL^2(M)_N$ should a direct sums of elements of the (dual maybe, not sure) of the Kac algebra, if I translated everything back correctly.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: I've read that the dual of $_NL^2(M)_M$ is $_ML^2(M^{op})_N$ with $M^{op}$ the opposite algebra of $M$. What do you mean by "a direct sum of elements", what's the irreducible bimodule related to an "element" ? This decomposition is unique, right ?

Comment: The dual of ${}_N L^2(M)_M$ can be identified with ${}_ML^2(M)_N$, see remark 6.13 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5671 For the other, let us consider for simplicity $N=M^G\subset M$ for finite group G. Then ${}_NL^2(M)_N$ is the direct sum of over representations $\pi\in\hat G$ with multiplicity $d\pi$ the dimension of $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $_RM_R:={}_R(L^2R\otimes_{\mathbb C} L^2R)_R$, where the first $R$ acts on the first $L^2R$ and the second $R$ acts on the second $L^2R$.
Its algebra of $R$-$R$-bimodule endomorphisms is $R^{\mathrm{op}}\,\bar\otimes\, R$.

Using (misleading!) intuition from the representation theory of separable $C^*$-algebras, one might guess that every MASA in $R^{\mathrm{op}}\bar\otimes R$ gives rise to a direct integral decomposition of $_RM_R$ into irreducible $R$-$R$-bimodules. But that is not true. There is no way of writing $_RM_R$ as a direct integral of irreducible bimodules.

<s>Indeed, suppose that ${}_R(M_x)_R$, $x\in X$, are irreducible bimodules, and that $\int^\oplus_{x\in X} {}_R(M_x)_R dx$ is an $R$-$R$-bimodule that is isomorphic to $_RM_R$. Then for every $M_x$, the left and right actions of $R$ induce an action of $R\,\bar\otimes\, R^{\mathrm{op}}$ on $M_x$. But $R\,\bar\otimes\, R^{\mathrm{op}}$ is type $II$ and does not admit irreducible representations. Contradiction.</s>

My argument above is not valid.
Nevertheless, I still maintain that there is no way of writing $_RM_R$ as a direct integral of irreducible bimodules.

---

Here is where my intuition comes from:

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two factors such that one type II (or III) while the other is of type I.
Let $_{R_1}M_{R_2}:={}_{R_1}(L^2{R_1}\otimes_{\mathbb C} L^2{R_2})_{R_2}$, where the first $R_1$ acts on the first $L^2R_1$ and the second $R_2$ acts on the second $L^2R_2$.
Its algebra of bimodule endomorphisms is $R_1^{\mathrm{op}}\,\bar\otimes\, R_2$.

Using (misleading!) intuition from the representation theory of separable $C^*$-algebras, one might guess that every MASA in $R_1^{\mathrm{op}}\bar\otimes R_2$ gives rise to a direct integral decomposition of $_{R_1}M_{R_2}$ into irreducible $R_1$-$R_2$-bimodules. But that is not true. There is no way of writing $M$ as a direct integral of irreducible bimodules as... *there are no
irreducible $R_1$-$R_2$-bimodules*!

Comment: Andre, I trust you about $_RM_R$, but if your argument is not valid, how do you know that $_RM_R$ is not completely reducible? Is it intuition or do you read this result somewhere ?

Comment: @André: I think you're correct. If you look at the coarse correspondence as an $M=R\otimes R^{op}$ module, then sub $M$-modules correspond to projections in the commutant $M'\cong R\otimes R$, which is type II$_1$. Irreducible sub $M$-modules should correspond to minimal projections, of which there are none. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dave: That's not how things work. The "summands" in a direct integral decomposition are not sub(bi)modules.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: can you complete your answer? Anyway I will accept it thanks to this meta-post: [Acceptation of partial answers](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1890/34538)