# The completely reducible bimodules coming from subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

This post is a sequel of: [Are all the R-R-bimodules completely reducible?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149839/34538)

*Question*: For which (as general as possible) class  of subfactors $(N \subset M)$, the bimodule $_NM_M$ is known completely reducible?   Is there counter-examples or open cases?

Following the comments of Marcel it seems that $_NM_M$ is completely reducible iff $N' \cap M$ is a type ${\rm I}$ von Neumann algebra. How to prove that in details?

Comment: Finite dimensional relative commutant should be sufficient.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: where is the proof? and for the general case, do you know (or expect) a counter-example?

Comment: The $\mathrm{Hom}(_NM_M,_NM_M)$ can be identified with the relative commutant. If you take a standard half-sided modular inclusion the relative commutant is a type III factor.

Comment: Corollary 2.9 in http://journals.math.ac.vn/acta/pdf/0803209.pdf

Comment: @MarcelBischoff; Nice! So if I understand well, $_NM_M$ is completely reducible iff $N' \cap M$ is a type I von Neumann algebra, right?

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: what do you mean by "standard half-sided modular inclusion"?

Comment: Take any conformal net $A$ and take $A((1,\infty)) \subset A((0,\infty))$. Then the relative commutant contains $A((0,1))$.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: Let $(N \subset M)$ be your example, then is $_NM_N$ also a non completely reducible $N$-$N$-bimodule? If so, it it possible to transfer this example in the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ case for having a certified answer to the previous question?

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: there is a direct example. Let $M$ and $N$ be ${\rm II}_1$ factors and take the subfactor $(\mathbb{C} \otimes N \subset M \otimes N)$, then the relative commutant is $(\mathbb{C} \otimes N)' \cap (M \otimes N) = (B(H) \otimes N') \cap (M \otimes N) = M \otimes \mathbb{C}$.